# Handshake error in client (OS Error: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION(tls_record.cc:586) in flutter app when trying to do a post/get request

Tags: node.js, http, flutter, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Node.js rest APIs, which I am using in my flutter app to do requests accordingly, but when I tried to do the same I am getting an exception that is:

```
Exception has occurred.
HandshakeException (HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION(tls_record.cc:586)))
```

I am doing the request with the http client like:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
const _baseUrl = https://domain.in/api/

http.Response response = await http.post(
      _baseUrl + 'user/login',
      body: json.encode(_authData),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    ).catchError((onError){
      print(onError);
    });
```

It was working with http but it is not working with https.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem. The problem was with the server-side ssl certificate.
I changed the request from https to http.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server side error because of your nginx `ssl` configuration.

`ssl_protocols` line in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file should look like this :

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```

If you use extra file for your `ssl` settings in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` or `yourdomain` file in same path, for example a file called `ssl-params.conf`, add `ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;` line in this file too.

This is part of my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file:

```
server {
    #Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.net www.domain.net;

    # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem;

    #Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf; // <- !pay attention this line

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This is my `/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf` file:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; 
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem; 
ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s; 
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

And this is `ssl_protocols` line in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

This settings solved my problem.
I hope helps others too.